# Ajuda em VB.NET usando Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: vb.net, json.net

Olá, eu tenho esse código:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim channel As JObject = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("C:\stats.json"))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Eu quero fazer o texto da Label1 ser o `points` e a Label2 ser o `name`.
Aqui está o JSON:

```
{
  'points': 0,
  'name': 'John Doe'
}
```

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Porque o código está dentro de um Timer? é assim mesmo que vai funcionar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom eu não sei o motivo do código estar dentro de um `Timer`, deve ter uma razão para isso, mas a pergunta é referente ao `json` para pegar cada valor `points` e `name` e passar respectivamente para `Label1` e `Label2`, com o método `GetValue` vai recuperar cada item e é muito simples agora passar para as duas `Labels`, exemplo:

```
Dim channel As JObject = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("./stats.json"))
Dim points = channel.GetValue("points").ToString()
Dim name = channel.GetValue("name").ToString()

Label1.Text = points
Label2.Text = name
```

Uma outra maneira é codificar uma classe com os seguintes campos:

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property points As Integer
    Public Property name As String
End Class
```

e deserializar o conteúdo do `json`, exemplo:

```
Dim RootObject = DirectCast(Newtonsoft _
    .Json _
    .JsonConvert _
    .DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText("./stats.json"), 
            GetType(Rootobject)), Rootobject)


Label1.Text = RootObject.points.ToString()
Label2.Text = RootObject.name
```

São as formas que eu vejo para resolver o seu problema.